# Joomla v.3.2.1 emails not sent - BreezingForms for Joomla! Lite (build 827)

Tags: joomla, breezingforms

**PHP Built On:** Linux 2.6.32-458.23.2.lve1.2.45.el6.x86_64
**PHP Version:** 5.3.27
**Web Server:** LiteSpeed
**Joomla! Version:** Joomla! 3.2.1 Stable [ Ember ] 18-December-2013 14:30 GMT
**Joomla! Platform Version:** Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ]
**Component:** BreezingForms Lite (build 827)
**MySQL Database Version:** 5.1.71
**MySQL Database Collation:** utf8_general_ci

In System -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Mail Settings -> Mailer
I have tested PHP Mail, Sendmail, SMTP

In configuration.php

```
public $mailonline = '1';
```

I see the records in Components -> BreezingForms -> Manage Records but emails from the form are not send.

No error in error.log file! No javascript errrors!

The most weird thing is that when a user Registers or submits the Contact Form (build with Components -> Contacts -> Contacts) I get the emails!

Please advice!

Comment: Might be best you contact the developer of Breezing forms. I would have thought that this could possibly be a bug where nothing happens with certain variables in place

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I have already done what you suggested http://crosstec.de/en/forums/5-bugs/97759-joomla-v-3-2-1-emails-not-sent-lite-build-827.html , but after 1 day and 19 hours, none has responded! Not even that is a bug... or to say "I can not answer because you have to pay"... or something! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please make sure you are using a default email address in BFs main configuration that matches the domain part your site is running on. That email is also used as standard sender address.

People often don't receive emails to their accounts because their servers block emails with different domain parts.

By the way, I am from the crosstec team, and you are neither ignored nor get told to buy support. Sometimes things simply can take a day or two, we are just people, too.

Regards,
Markus

Comment: The past couple of days I am trying to figure out why I don't receive the email from the form. Although you are right about the email address matching the domain part, I believe the bug is when you put in the settings of the form a different email (from the same domain) other than the default (configuration). So, when I selected "To Default Address" form the advanced settings of the form, guess what... It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I enabled the Cache Settings in Joomla.  Once I disabled it, the BreezingForm Lite started to work again.  Weird bug maybe?  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is not the right answer in this instance, but I will answer in case others arrive here from Google.

Make sure you have ticked the "**mail notification**" checkbox.  If that is unticked then no mail is sent.

[image]